# How can I get my name "Easy Widgets" (separated by a space) to be indexed higher than "EasyWidgets" (combined)?

Tags: seo, search-results, google-ranking

The name of my business and website is "Easy Widgets". I have a Google business listing and website that both show up on page one for "EasyWidgets".

Google asks me if I meant "Easy Widgets", but when I click that to update the search or manually search for "Easy *(space)* Widgets", my business listing disappears and my website is found on page two.

How can I improve the position of "Easy Widgets" versus "EasyWidgets", so that my Google business listing, which also contains a space, would rank higher?

I see questions about the opposite problem (getting two keywords to be indexed as one), but my business would be more visible with a space between the keywords since that's what the business name is and represents.

Comment: I edited this quite a bit so that we could reopen it (it was too broad as it was), so hopefully it's still close to what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

First things first.

The notion of using keywords for search is junk SEO. Throw that idea out and think in terms of sentences. Think about it this way, your dog understands simple word associations. Are you saying that Google is about as intelligent as your dog? Of course not! Google was created as a semantic (linguistics) based search engine. Today, semantic is almost as fully implemented as anyone can imagine. This means that Google has never made term matches and never will. Any apparent term match is a byproduct of highlighting search terms last in the process while actually writing the results page. Nothing more. All the SEO advice you see related to keywords is junk based upon extremely flawed assumptions.

Second.

Easy Widgets versus EasyWidgets is a misnomer. It is a false comparison. Both are not equal. The first are search terms, the second is not. Nor is just Easy Widgets a good way to validate your sites performance. The fact that Google wants to suggest another search is a byproduct of another two word term you are not using. You have to think of whole language and how people speak, search, and so on. It is not about keywords. Not even close. It is about sentences with subject, predicate, and object. People are no longer just entering two word searches as much as partial or complete sentences/questions. Keep this in mind.

I took a look at your original terms and site. One of the terms you are wishing to rank for is not one that people would use to find your site making the whole Easy Widgets search a poor gauge for performance. You can use Google trends to research how people use search for certain terms and what topics you need to concentrate on.

https://www.google.com/trends/

*Use Google trends to not only search topic clues, but how your site would be found.*

As far as your site.

I took a look at your site. It is scant. You have three web pages that are not properly signalling to search engines what you need them to know. Any site with just three pages cannot rank over sites with much more content. It is about the strength of the signals you are sending. You could possibly be better off with a single page listing all of your products on the home page until you have more content to offer. It is not enough to just say you sell something, but to distinguish yourself from the pack. If you chose not to create a single page, that is okay. Work with the ones you have. I do warn you however, that there is product overlap between the home page and another page. You should remove some of this. This is why I was recommending a single page.

If you were to search for *widgets for sale* (obviously replace widgets for your product term in your original question) in Google, the first site is a good example of a site that performs well. Study this site for clues.

Sending the right signals.

There are several issues with your site sending the right signals. Here are a few.

1] Your title tag is too long and starts with branding. Your title tag should not exceed 55 characters. Period. Your branding should be last. The beginning should say what your site is about. For example:

Shop for Premium Widgets | EasyWidgets

Your title tag should be conversational, and meet the expectations people who should find your site. You are a shop. People who are looking to purchase widgets are shopping. While this is not the best example of a title tag, it is standard enough to get you started. The pipe character separates semantic clusters (do not worry about what that means) into groups. The first is what your site is about, the last is your brand.

You will want a unique title tag per page that properly describes your page. For example, *evening widgets* or *gift widgets*. You can see that linguistically, I added a modifier to widgets. When you create a page from your home page, it is a sub-topic. If your sites topic is widgets, then when you create a page, ask yourself what is the sub-topic. I use the example question, "What about...?" In this case, What about widgets? You have gift widgets, you have evening widgets, you have low fat widgets, etc. These are modifiers.

You can simply modify the example title above to include the modifier.

Keep in mind that your title tag is used in the search engine result page (SERP) and must be appealing to people who are searching. You need to entice them to click on your link.

2] Your description meta-tag is not too bad. I would suggest thinking in terms of specifically what each page is about. Your description should fit the page. Your home page is about you and what you do. Your other pages are about a particular subset of widgets. You need to modify these to send the right signals.

Keep in mind that description meta-tags are used in the SERPs and must be appealing to people. You need to entice them to click on your link.

3] You do not have a proper h1 tag. Your h1 tag is an image. Never do this! You should have an h1 tag per page that is text similar to the title tag and description meta-tag.

Think of it this way. Your title tag is short but descriptive. Your h1 tag should be similar but not identical but not as short. It also describes what the page is about, except that it should be longer and more descriptive. Your description meta-tag should also relate to the title tag and h1 tag except that it is even longer and more descriptive. Stay on target with the pages subject and be conversational.

4] Yesterday, when I went to your home page, there was a pop-up asking to sign-up. Never do this! This is poor user experience (UX) and will drive your bounce rate up. This means that when people click on your link in search, they see the pop-up, get irritated, and click the back button to continue searching. Google is looking for pop-ups and is down-grading sites for poor UX.

5] You need a Contact and About page. Your contact page is how people can reach you. For search engines, this is an indicator of real company 5h17 (RCS). Search engines do not extend trust to sites that sell product that do not have a name, address, phone (NAP), and especially e-mail or contact form. Your About page should be about who you are, where you are located (generally), and what you do. Personal profiles are good here. For example, Bob Smith, an award winning pastry chef with 20 years experience in the culinary arts, creates widgets of almost magical experience and culinary refinement.

6] Schema.org mark-up. Your site does not use mark-up. This is extremely important if you are selling. You will want to use mark-up for your contact information and products. This is a bit technical, but well worth the effort.

7] Warm and fuzzies. While this is not technical, you want to give people the warm and fuzzies about who you are, what you do, and what you sell. It is not just about widgets. It is about how your widgets are better, how your widgets improve the lives of your users, how your widgets feel, taste, smell, look, etc. Bring emotion to your site. For example, *Our widgets are crafted from the finest ingredients and are sumptuous to the touch and pallet. You will smell and taste the love we use to create the finest product on the market. With our widgets, you will be able to enjoy and share the luxury that comes from a product as skillfully crafted as our widgets.* Think in terms of emotional triggers and how people see, use, and enjoy your product.

You will not only convert more users to sales, but also find more search users.

That is a start. Enough to get you better performance. But it is only a start. SEO is about constant improvement. Content is how people find your site. I encourage you to create content about the widget making process, ingredients, history, your love of widgets from when you were a little boy/girl, etc. The more you can add, the more opportunities there are for you to find search users. Business is like duck hunting. There is a reason why we use a shotgun instead of a rifle. The odds of getting a duck greatly improves. Adding more content is like using a shotgun in duck hunting.

Comment: This is a good answer.

Comment: @JCL1178 Thanks!! I try. Sometimes I hit a home run, sometimes just a base hit, and sometimes I just plain strike out. Still, it is good just to get up to bat. It means I am still in the game. As long as I don't get traded. ;-)

Comment: You'll be traded for a webmaster to be named later. (Note to the global audience: this is an American baseball joke and trust me, it is funny)

Answer (score 0):

SEO is a very broad area. Here is a breakdown of the steps for rating on an intended keyword:

1. Create content relevant to the keyword(s) on your site.
2. Put your most important keywords in your URI, Title and Header. *Try* not to use them again in other locations (article, subheading, footer, etc.).
3. Get as many backlinks as possible for your term(s). Relevant (exact or semantic) anchor text helps.
4. Users looking for your keywords have to give good feedback. This clicking on your listing, using your site and not bouncing back to Google.

There specifics involved with each of these actions that an expert can help with - however if you get the basics done, it's easier for someone to critique an existing site than tell you how to create one from scratch.